# ASP.NET MVC Create querystring from form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

I am trying to create a simple search box that results in something like http://www.example.com/Search?s=searchTerm   I have the routing setup so that it accepts a url like this, and does the right thing. The problem I'm having is getting the form to create the querystring. I have tried many variations of:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { ???? })) {%>
<input id="submitSearch" class="searchBox" type="text" runat="server"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" /> <%} %>
```

I'm not sure how to setup the Html.BeginForm so it grabs the submitSearch value and passes it to /Search?s=valueHere.  This seems like I am missing something easy.

Comment: why does your HTML `<input>` tag use the `runat` attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `name` on the input box to `s`.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { })) { %>
    <input id="s" name="s" class="searchBox" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
<% } %>
```

Also, note that I changed the `id` to `s` as well, since common practice is to have the same value for `name` and `id`. However, it is only the `name` attribute that affects the query string name in the request.
And as David noted in a comment, the `runat="server"` is not needed in ASP.NET MVC.